# Choose which option is selected in select tag

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I would like to choose which option is selected in a combobox and I want to be able to change the selected option in my Typescript.

I have only two option : yes or no. I want choose which one is selected when my combobox appears

EDIT :

It's an answer to a question from an user and i want show this combobox to allow the user to edit his answer

HTML :

```
<select class="form-control custom-select" name="uIsAdmin" id="uIsAdmin">
    <option *ngFor="let useradmin of userIsAdmin">{{useradmin}}</option>
</select>
```

TypeScript:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.userIsAdmin=[
      "yes", "no"
    ];
  }
```

Comment: Do you want to set a default value? If so, you can achieve this by 
<option *ngFor="let useradmin of userIsAdmin" [selected]="option === 'yes'">{{useradmin}}</option>

Comment: i want to able to change the set value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a default value you can set the `selected` property

```
<option *ngFor="let useradmin of userIsAdmin" [selected]="useradmin === 'yes'">{{useradmin}}</option>
```

To change the selected value programatically, you can use ngModel

```
<select [(ngModel)]="myChoice" class="form-control custom-select" name="uIsAdmin" id="uIsAdmin">
    <option *ngFor="let useradmin of userIsAdmin">{{useradmin}}</option>
</select>
```

TS:

```
const myChoice = "yes";
```

Nevertheless - with your code you provide a multiple choice for a use case that should probably only allow either yes or no. In this case you should use a **radio button group**.

Comment: so, with : [(ngModel)]="yes" the option selected will be yes ?